# I can't see usb at boot options, how can I fix that?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi, refind

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 by formating all hdd. Everything is perfect, but for work reasons I have to install Windows. I downloaded company image (as I know untouched image) of Windows and wrote to USB with Rufus.

Now problem starts with the booting options, when I click to F12 for BIOS Booting Options (the white menu on blue background that listes HDD, CD-ROM etc.) there was only one option that says "ubuntu" and when I click that it directs me to Ubuntu. When I click to F2 for BIOS menu it redirects me to GRUB (only OS so again to Ubuntu). So I find something call rEFInd so maybe it can find my USB (it worked on my another laptop before), and no luck still I can't see my USB and all I could find is Ubuntu. (EFI i guess)

I am not expert at EFI or UEFI or other protocols, so if you can explain how can I get out of this cycle and reach to my bootable usb for someone new to this?

Comment: Which version of Windows? W7 can't boot to UEFI, only 8 and 10 can, and thus W7 is not visible in UEFI boot menu.

Comment: @Michal I tried both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 images, no luck at in either of them.

Comment: @Michal W7 in a USB flash drive can; in a DVD it's true it can't. Either Microsoft's official tool or Rufus add the EFI boot folder and files.

Comment: @mtilhan I'm sorry but this is off-topic.

Comment: @CelticWarrior usb has efi folder in it, and only that laptop (which has only Ubuntu 16.04) can't boot from it. So I am curious how is this an off topic?

Comment: It may be so but it doesn't mean it has something to do with Ubuntu. and at the end of the day you're trying to boot an Windows installer to install Windows. Off-topic here.

Comment: I can be that laptop doesn't like that USB but work with others, USB2.0 / USB3.0 ports issues, some notebooks require setting up a user or admin password in order to "trust" booting from external media or a few other possibilities...

Comment: I was be able to boot usb before Ubuntu on that laptop. I did installed Ubuntu like that 2 weeks ago. How is this not caused by Ubuntu? It has everything to do with Ubuntu or Ubuntu installer.

Comment: @mtilhan No, absolutely NOT. Correlation is not causation. Installing an OS, any OS, doesn't change or in any way interfere with BIOS/UEFI. It happens that some UEFIs (with fastboot enabled) behave differently when bare-metal and after an OS is installed (faster boot giving almost no time to interrupt the booting process in order to access UEFI settings but always possible with ESC or other vendor specific key pressed *immediately* after powering on) but that's all. NOTHING to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @CelticWarrior but all I can access to Ubuntu stuff, like grub or rEFInd, if I am not going to ask the questions to askubuntu where can I get help? I understand it is not because of Ubuntu but it can only be solve with Ubuntu as I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47280/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-mtilhan).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I had look to that question before. There are important differences between my question and that question. I am not trying a Dual boot just remove Ubuntu and install Windows. Also at there they just say "Open a space then, install Windows" and that is my problem. I can't reach the USB at booting after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: That's not clear at all from your question. You wrote “I installed Ubuntu 16.04” and “I have to install Windows”. No hint whatsoever that you want to remove Ubuntu in the process.

Comment: In that case: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](/q/133533/175814)